# populate=* in strapi i am getting all the fields from relation table but i do not get field with content type media

Tags: strapi

Strapi version: 4.11.2

In User table i have added field called "avatar" which is of type media(single media). now i am using populate=* as in following url and i am getting all the relation attributes from user table beside "avatar".

```
http://localhost:1337/api/articles?sort=id:DESC&populate=*
```

It looks like relation is working fine because i am getting all the fields from "User" table, only one field with type media is missing.

how can i retrieve "avatar", using api URL as above?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question right you have a single or collection type that contains a relation that you are trying to populate.

In this case you have to populate your object two levels deep to access the media in the relation.

`http://localhost:1337/api/articles?populate[User][populate]=*`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have article collection that have relations with User table where field name is user **(this is important)**, so your populate query will be look

> populate[users][populate]=avatar

so the end URL will be

> http://localhost:1337/api/articles?sort=id:DESC&populate[users][populate]=avatar

And all set!